# Python: try/except call returning wrong value, calling except clause unneeded

Tags: python, recursion, try-except

In the attached code snippet the goal is to receive a user input and, depending if it is an integer or not, return the integer or call the function recursively until a valid integer is given.

```
def verify_input(msg, str_exp=True, req_str=None):
    user_input = input(msg)
    if str_exp:
        pass # TODO: implement later
    else:
        try:
            return int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            verify_input("Enter a whole number please. ", str_exp=False)
```

If user responds correctly (i.e. an integer) on the *first function call* the integer is indeed returned from the function.

Problem is, if user misbehaves and *firstly* doesn't respond with an integer, only giving integer on *subsequent* tries, I can see, working with a debugger, that the `try` clause *always* goes to the `except` clause... even though the second call is with an integer.

**To sum up:**
verify_input(12) # => returns 12
verify_input("Hello") # => return a call to verify_input ---> user gives answer "12" => returns `None`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a `return` when you call `verify_input` in the `except ValueError` block.

Comment: @dano that sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: @C.B. Fair point. I converted it to an answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761 to avoid recursion

Comment: Excellent link, @jonrsharpe, thank you for that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `return` when you call `verify_input` in the `except ValueError` block:

```
try:
    return int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    return verify_input("Enter a whole number please. ", str_exp=False)
```